# Libgdx Car bouncing

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I have created a basic car with libgdx and now I am trying to create a ground surface for it to drive on. At first I just made a static fixture using a chainshape with 2 points both far off the screen in both directions. Here is the code that worked.

```
ChainShape groundShapetest = new ChainShape();
groundShapetest.createChain(new float[]{-100, 0.1f , 10000, 0.1f});
environment.createFixture(groundShapetest, 0);
groundShapetest.dispose();
```

This worked fine and the car moved smoothly as expected (no bouncing). Next I wanted to add more interesting terrain and tried building ground from many small Chainshapes all set back to back.

```
while (last.x <= rightEdge)
{
next = GenerateTerrainContour(h, last.x);//, w/(float)num_sections);
EdgeShape groundShapetest = new EdgeShape();
groundShapetest.set(last, next);
environment.createFixture(groundShapetest, 0);
groundShapetest.dispose();
last = next;
}
```

GenerateTerrainContour() just returns the next point of a random contour.
When I do this and enable the car motor the car starts to bounce randomly as if it is hitting something or going over rough ground. The Ground is totally smooth and it still does it even if I set the y component of the GenerateTerrainContour() to always return 0.

I am not even sure how to debug this because there is obviously some force effecting the car but I'm not sure where it is coming from. Any help would be much appreciated. 
I can post more code if that would be helpful?

In case anyone wants to try to simulate this I have created a simple project with just a wheel and gave it a torque. It does the same bouncing thing on the ground i have created. All you have to do is copy this code into a libgdx project and you will see what I am talking about. I must be missing something simple but what it is I don't know.

```
package com.mygdx.game;


import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ChainShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;

public class groundTest extends ApplicationAdapter {


private static final float WORLD_TO_BOX = 0.01f;
private static final float BOX_TO_WORLD = 100f;
private static final float TIMESTEP = 1 / 60f;;
private static final int VELOCITYITERATIONS = 8;
private static final int POSITIONITERATIONS = 3;
private static final String TITLE = "GND_TEST";
private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
private static final int PPM = 50;
private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;   
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Car car;
Body lw;


@Override
public void create () {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/PPM;
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/PPM;
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f), true);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);
    camera.update();
    createGND();
    //initCar(w,h);
    makeWheel();


    debugRenderer =  new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    }

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width/PPM;
    camera.viewportHeight = height/PPM;

    camera.update();
    // camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2f, camera.viewportHeight/2f, 0);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.graphics.setTitle(TITLE + " -- FPS: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());


//  camera.position.set(car.getChassis().getPosition().x + ((float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / PPM)/4.0f, camera.viewportHeight/3.0f, 0);
    camera.position.set(lw.getPosition().x, 0, 0);

    camera.update();


    if(DEBUG)
    {


        //Matrix4 cameraCopy = camera.combined.cpy();
        //debugRenderer.render(world, cameraCopy.scl(BOX_TO_WORLD));
        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);

    }

    world.step(TIMESTEP, VELOCITYITERATIONS, POSITIONITERATIONS);


}


private void createGND()
{
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
    Body ground = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    //Uncomment the next 4 lines to get gronud that causes no bouncing
    //ChainShape groundNoBounce = new ChainShape(); 
    //groundNoBounce.createChain(new float[]{-10f, 0, 1000f, 0});
    //ground.createFixture(groundNoBounce, 0.0f).setRestitution(0); 
    //groundNoBounce.dispose();

    // comment this loop out if above uncommented
    for(int x = -10; x < 1000; x+=1)
    {
        ChainShape groundBox = new ChainShape(); 
        groundBox.createLoop(new float[]{(float)x,-3.0f, 
                                (float)x+1.0001f, -3.0f,
                                (float)x+1.0001f,0.0f, 
                                (float)x, 0.0f});

        ground.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f).setRestitution(0); 

        groundBox.dispose();
    }
}



private void makeWheel()
{
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(0, 10);

    FixtureDef wheelFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();


    wheelFixtureDef.density = 2f;
    wheelFixtureDef.friction = 50;//0.8f;
    wheelFixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;//25f;//0.5f;            
    // 
    CircleShape wheelShape = new CircleShape();
    wheelShape.setRadius(0.5f);

    wheelFixtureDef.shape = wheelShape;

    lw = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    lw.createFixture(wheelFixtureDef).setRestitution(0.0f);

    lw.applyTorque(-3000f, true);
    camera.zoom = .25f;
    camera.update();

}
}
```

Comment: When you specify a 0 you say the fixture density will be 0, but fixtures also have a restitution property. Maybe if you try to set it to 0 too?
[LibGdx Fixture Restitution](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/FixtureDef.html#restitution)

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution. Here is a link with the fix I used. It a bit of a hack and I hope Box2d works this bug out but it appears that the ball is colliding with the edges of the segments even though they are all exactly the same height.
This worked for me.
http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=7917

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly it's not really a bug. More info here http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/ghost-vertices Typically you would use a chain shape to create the terrain as a single long line, instead of a bunch of squares as you're doing which kinda defeats the point of a chain shape and ends up with the same problem that polygons have.